# Comprehensive matching across a list of vectors

Tags: r, comparison, match, matching

I am trying to match between all available combinations of vectors.

For example, i have 4 vectors:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4)
b<-c(1,2,6,7)
c<-c(1,2,8,9)
d<-c(3,6,8,2)
```

The intended output should be able to tell me:

- similarity between a & b: 1, 2
- similarity between a & c: 1, 2
- similarity between a & d: 2, 3
- similarity between b & c: 1, 2
- similarity between b & d: 2, 6
- similarity between c & d: 2, 8
- similarity between a & b & c: 1, 2
- similarity between b & c & d: 2
- similarity between a & c & d: 2
- similarity between a & b & d: 2
- similarity between a & b & c & d: 2

Does R have a function that does such comparison/ matching?

For simplicity, the number of vectors is set at 4 for now. I am in fact dealing with 100s of vectors and would like to match/intersect/compare between all possible combinations of vectors. For example with 4 vectors, there will be a possible 4C2+4C3+4C4=11 available combinations. With 100 vectors, there will be a possible 100C100+ 100C99+100C98+...+100C2 available combinations

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`intersect` seems to do what you want. It only does pairs of vectors at a time though eg

```
intersect(a, b) # 1 2
intersect(b, intersect(c, d)) # 2
```

If you want a shorthand to intersect more than 2, try `Reduce` (`?Reduce`)

```
# intersection of a/b/c/d
Reduce(intersect, list(a, b, c, d), a)
# intersection of b/c/d
Reduce(intersect, list(b, c, d), b)
```

`Reduce` will successively apply `intersect` to the list and the result of the previous intersect call, starting with `intersect(b, b)` (the `init` argument I just set to one of the vectors to be intersected, as the intersection of a set with itself is the set).

---

If you wanted a way to go through all (pairs, tuples, quadruples) of (a, b, c, d) and return the intersection, you could try

1. generate all combinations of (a, b, c, d) in lengths 2 (pairs), 3 (tuples), 4 (quadruples)

   ```
   combos = lapply(2:4, combn, x=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), simplify=F)
   # [[1]]
   # [[1]][[1]]
   # [1] "a" "b"
   # [[1]][[2]]
   # [1] "a" "c"
   # ...
   # [[2]]
   # [[2]][[1]]
   # [1] "a" "b" "c"
   # [[2]][[2]]
   # [1] "a" "b" "d"
   # ...
   # [[3]]
   # [[3]][[1]]
   # [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
   ```
2. Flatten it out to just a list of character vectors

   ```
   combos = unlist(combos, recursive=F)
   # [[1]]
   # [1] "a" "b"
   # ...
   # [[10]]
   # [1] "b" "c" "d"
   # [[11]]
   # [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
   ```
3. For each set, call `Reduce` as specified above. We can use (e.g.) `get("a")` to get the variable `a`; or `mget(c("a", "b", "c")` to get the variables `a`, `b`, `c` in a list. If your variables are columns in a dataframe, then you can modify appropriately.

   ```
   intersects = lapply(combos, function (varnames) {
       Reduce(intersect, mget(varnames, inherits=T), get(varnames[1]))
   })
   # add some labels for clarity.
   # You will probably actually want to /do/ something with the
   #  resulting intersections rather than this.
   names(intersects) <- sapply(combos, paste, collapse=", ")
   intersects
   # $`a, b`
   # [1] 1 2
   # $`a, c`
   # [1] 1 2
   # ...
   # $`a, b, c, d`
   # [1] 2
   ```

You will need to modify to suit how your data is in R; e.g. columns of a dataframe vs named vectors in the workspace and so on.
You might also just prefer a `for` loop from step 3. onwards rather than all the `*apply` depending on what you want to *do* with the result. (Plus, if you have many vectors, holding all the intersections simultaneously in memory might not be a good idea anyway).

Comment: This looks like the solution im looking for. I guess u are right about the memory part. Is there another more elegant and less memory heavy method to do such a comparison then?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, just do a for loop rather than doing everything simultaneously. I am sure you could do something very efficient with the `data.table` package too, but it will be a bit of a learning curve.